# Shorting long if statement

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have spent hours making a tic tac toe game just using mainly if else statements, some of the code I just copy and pasted...

How would I just create one instance of the code, then refer to it later on? - when I need that code, instead of just copy and pasting massive lines of code each time. In this block of code, I am getting a random number between 1 to 10 this number will be stored in RI... then when it's Ai's turn the computer will randomly input an X in the button, then using this code it will check to determine if the computer has won. I hope that make sense =)

```
do
{
    storeRI = rc.Next(0, 10); //storing random number into storeRI so it can be used later on in life. 
    if (storeRI == 1 && btn1.Text == "")
    {
        btn1.Text = "X";
        Turn = 1;
        if (btn1.Text == "X" & btn2.Text == "X" & btn3.Text == "X")
        {
            btn1.BackColor = Color.Green;
            btn2.BackColor = Color.Green;
            btn3.BackColor = Color.Green;

            XScore += 1;
            lblPScoreX.Text = XScore.ToString();

            foreach (Button btn in buttonList)
                 btn.Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (btn1.Text == "X" & btn4.Text == "X" & btn7.Text == "X")
        {
             btn1.BackColor = Color.Green;
             btn4.BackColor = Color.Green;
             btn7.BackColor = Color.Green;

             XScore += 1;
             lblPScoreX.Text = XScore.ToString();

             foreach (Button btn in buttonList)
                btn.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

for example this code, is some of the code, that I have copied atleast 10 times, and it just makes me code look ugly and really hard to read.

Comment: Your title question asks about "this if statement", but they question body is vague on exactly what code you are talking about.

Comment: btn1.Text is always X so why do you check it anyway ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> for example this code, is some of the code, that I have copied atleast 10 times

Any time you have copied code, you should try to move it into a method.  You can then just call the method directly.  In your case, a method could easily accept the three buttons to affect, and work on them directly.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, you could try to highlight one of the blocks, then right click and Refactor > Extract Method.

Comment: Interesting! I'll have too look into this more!

Answer (score 2):

The refactoring technique you may want to look into is [Consolidate Duplicate Conditional Fragments](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/consolidateDuplicateConditionalFragments.html)

```
if (btn1.Text == "X" & btn2.Text == "X" & btn3.Text == "X")
{
    btn2.BackColor = Color.Green;
    btn3.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
else if (btn1.Text == "X" & btn4.Text == "X" & btn7.Text == "X")
{
    btn4.BackColor = Color.Green;
    btn7.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
else
{
    return/break/continue; // hard to tell which you what as you have a do without a corresponding while
}

btn1.BackColor = Color.Green;

XScore += 1;
lblPScoreX.Text = XScore.ToString();
foreach (Button btn in buttonList)
{
    btn.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   bool TestWin(Button btnA, Button btnB, button btnC)
   {
           if (btnA.Text == "X" & btnB.Text == "X" & btnC.Text == "X")
           {
                    btnA.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    btnB.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    btnC.BackColor = Color.Green;

                    XScore += 1;
                    lblPScoreX.Text = XScore.ToString();

                    foreach (Button btn in buttonList)
                    {
                         btn.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    return true;
           }
           return false;
     }


     if (!TestWin(btn1, btn2, btn3))
           TestWin(btn1, btn4, btn7);
```

Comment: I was going to post this but you beat me to it :). +1 though

Comment: What does the "1" mean? and what does the function testwin do?

Comment: Probably add in a `string XorO` and then check to see if you have a row of Xs or Os then return the winning character, or `string.empty` if there is no winner.

Comment: @Glen : what "1"?  The only "1" in there came directly from your code.  Do you mean the "!" in the if()?  It means "not", as is "Did TestWin not return true".  TestWin() tests if the given three buttons won the gave.  The function returns true if so, or false if not.

Comment: Yes I meant the ! :) Thanks James!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (btn1.Text == "X")
{
    btn1.BackColor = Color.Green;
    if(btn2.Text == "X" & btn3.Text == "X")
        btn2.BackColor = Color.Green;
        btn3.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else if (btn4.Text == "X" & btn7.Text == "X")
    {
        btn4.BackColor = Color.Green;
        btn7.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    XScore += 1;
    lblPScoreX.Text = XScore.ToString();
    foreach (Button btn in buttonList)
    {
        btn.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting btn1.BackColor to green, even if neither of the next two if() are true (which would be wrong).  Look at the overall task-- he's playing tic-tac-toe. When X wins, he wants to color the winning run in green.  You have the square being colored before he wins.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with a long if else statement; it's better to have long readable code than short unmanageable code.

The one thing I can see that might help is to add in a method (with some changed to match your types):

```
public void ChangeButtonColor(Color thisColor, params Button[] buttons)
{
    foreach (Button thisButton in buttons)
    {
        thisButton.BackColor = thisColor
    }
}
```

then you can just add in to you code:

```
ChangeButtonColor(Color.Green, btn1, btn2, btn3);
```

This would save you some duplicated code.