# Duplicate codes: how can I prevent this?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an if else statement that identifies whether or not users have won my tic tac toe game however it's my mission! :) to make the code more compact and easier to read and I have lots of duplicate blocks of code and reduce the amount of code I have.

here's some of my code:

```
if (button1.Text == "X" & button2.Text == "X" & button3.Text == "X")
{
    foreach (Button button in addButton())
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        button2.BackColor = Color.Green;
        button3.BackColor = Color.Green;
        button.Enabled = false;
    }
}
else if (button1.Text == "X" & button4.Text == "X" & button7.Text == "X")
{
    foreach (Button button in addButton())
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        button4.BackColor = Color.Green;
        button7.BackColor = Color.Green;
        button.Enabled = false;
    }
}
else if (button1.Text == "X" & button5.Text == "X" & button9.Text == "X")
{
    foreach (Button button in addButton())
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        button4.BackColor = Color.Green;
        button7.BackColor = Color.Green;
        button.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

I was thinking maybe I could put this in a private method? But not sure if you actually can and I wouldn't know how to call upon the method, or even a class?

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you asked this same question today (regarding reducing amount of duplicate code):-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488204/shorting-long-if-statement
you can look into applying the technique that James suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an underlying data model to represent your data.  Let's say an array of ints.

```
int[,] board  = new int[,] {{0,0,0}, {0,0,0},{0,0,0}};
```

Then anytime an `X` is played, you set that position in the array to 1.

Anytime an `O` is played, you set the position to -1.

To check for a winner, you simply loop over your winning combinations, across, down, and the 2 cross patters and if they = 3 `X` wins and if they = -3 then `O` wins.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Button[] greenButtons = new Button[0]; // buttons to color in green
bool enabled = true; // value of Enabled for each of addButtons() to set

if (button1.Text == "X" & button2.Text == "X" & button3.Text == "X")
{
    greenButtons = new[] { button1, button2, button3 };
    enabled = false;
}
else if (button1.Text == "X" & button4.Text == "X" & button7.Text == "X")
{
    greenButtons = new[] { button1, button4, button7 };
    enabled = false;
}
else if (button1.Text == "X" & button5.Text == "X" & button9.Text == "X")
{
    greenButtons = new[] { button1, button4, button7 };
    enabled = false;
}

foreach (Button button in addButton())
{
    button.Enabled = enabled;
}
foreach (Button button in greenButtons)
{
    button.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```